# CSS background image fails to repeat below viewport

Tags: html, css, background-image

We repeat a textured background on [www.tekiki.com](http://www.tekiki.com), but anything below the viewport isn't repeated for some reason. The background renders as white.

Here are the CSS rules for our body element, which contains the repeating image:

```
font-family: 'Signika', verdana, tahoma, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 22px;
color: #5c5c5c;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
background: #cbe9f1 url(/images/web/main_bg.png) repeat top left;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

How do we get the background image to tile correctly? Thanks!

Comment: Has this question been answered? The linked webpage appears to be okay.

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately. The proposed solution introduces another bug on Chrome (Windows) as explained below.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `background-attachment: fixed` to `background-position: fixed`.

Comment: Or just remove that line.

Comment: Removing/editing the line fixes the white part, but it creates another issue: scrolling fast causes the whole page to go blank momentarily. We just updated the site so you can see what happens. Is there a solution that doesn't introduce another problem?

Comment: I could not reproduce that issue. It works fine for me in both FF and Chrome.

Comment: thanks, @chopper. are you on windows or os X? we're on windows and using chrome.

Comment: Ah I see. I'm on OS X.